# Why Jquery will work for link outside navbar but not inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

I have downloaded a JQuery plugin nav bar, this one http://jpanelmenu.com/ and in my code i have added link that will bring up some html to a  in the page without refreshing the whole page.I want to do this for each item in the nav bar, but when i write the same lines of code inside and outside the  tag the one outside will work but the one inside wont? Its the link that says Test Link I am wondering about here.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#loc a').click(function() {
     $('#loadPage').load('maps.html');
     return false;
   });
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jPanelMenu | A jQuery Plugin</title>

  <script src="openFiles.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jpanelmenu.com/js/lib/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jpanelmenu.com/js/lib/respond.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jpanelmenu.com/js/lib/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jpanelmenu.com/js/lib/jquery.jpanelmenu.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jpanelmenu.com/js/lib/plugins.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jpanelmenu.com/js/script.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="main">
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="." class="ss-list">Scot Free Music</a></h1>
    <a href="#menu" class="menu-trigger ss-icon">&#xED50;</a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#usage">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#inner-workings">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#animation">Artists</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#options">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#api">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tips">Tips &amp; Examples</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#license">License</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#changelog">History</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Location</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div id="loc">
        <h3><a href="#">Test Link</a></h3>
      </div>

    </nav>
    <div id="loc">
      <h3><a href="#">Test Link</a></h3>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div id="loadPage">
  </div>

  <footer class="main">
    <small>&copy; 2012 <a href="http://acolangelo.com" title="Anthony Colangelo | Web Design &amp; Development">Anthony Colangelo</a></small>
  </footer>

  <script src="http://use.typekit.net/koc4rlq.js"></script>
  <script>
    try {
      Typekit.load();
    } catch (e) {}
  </script>
  <!--
         <script type="text/javascript">
          var _gaq = _gaq || [];
          _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36076455-1']);
          _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        
          (function() {
          var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
          ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
          })();
         </script>
         -->

  <!--
        
         This is a concatenated and minifed file containing all scripts necessary to run this page.
        
         View my uncompressed script for this page at http://jpanelmenu.com/js/script.js
        
         Other Included Files:
        
          http://jpanelmenu.com/js/lib/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js
          http://jpanelmenu.com/js/lib/respond.js
          http://jpanelmenu.com/js/lib/highlight.min.js
          http://jpanelmenu.com/js/lib/jquery-1.9.0.js
          http://jpanelmenu.com/js/lib/jquery.jpanelmenu.min.js
          http://jpanelmenu.com/js/lib/plugins.js
          http://jpanelmenu.com/js/script.js
        
         -->
  <script src="js/script.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have two elements with `id="loc"`, probably that's why only one of them works. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: Your JQuery selector is targeting all link elements inside the div tag with id "loc". The links in your nav tag aren't inside this div so the JavaScript click handler will not be attached. Try changing your selector to something like $('nav a')

Comment: And as the first comment mentions, you have two div tags with the same ID...

Comment: Nah It still doesn't work when i delete the second one altogether and tried  $('nav a').click(function() on the first one,unfortunately

Comment: Maybe im misunderstanding your question, but i put your code into a JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/thfhdnkh/ and clicking the links in the nav now work. Is this not what you want?